# How can I save the graphics on panel as an image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

I am building a paint and it is working fine except that I am facing a problem with saving these graphs that I am drawing on the panel as an image. I have tried multiple ways to save these graphs, but they are saving as a white photo, nothing is displaying on the image when I am opening it. So, does any of you know how to save the graphs on the panel as an image?

Note: I am using WindowsFormApplication and C#.

Below are the codes that I used last time:

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(canves.Width, canves.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, canves.Width, canves.Height);
            canves.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);
           
            bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\spn\OneDrive\Pictures\b.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }
```

Comment: So, you're drawing something on a canvas, using its Graphics object, provided by the Paint event's / `OnPaint()` method's `PaintEventArgs` object (right? you should show that code). Now, do the same thing, this time using the Graphics object generated by `var g = Graphics.FromImage([Image])`, where `[Image]` is the Bitmap where you want to save your drawings.

Comment: `DrawToBitmap` triggers the Paint event and will capture the control and everything (and only what) you draw onto it in the Paint with e.Graphics.   [Doodle example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+Doodle)

Comment: See [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method

Comment: In my test, the code you provided can save the graphic normally. So please make sure that the graphic has been drawn on the Panel before saving.